# Nginx + Django errors when loading ccs files in production

Tags: html, css, django, nginx

I have seen many similar posts but nothing has been able to make the trick for me. Browser throws me this kind of error for all my css files when i load my static. 
When I collect static it works fine plus when I run findstatic it points me to right directory. SO I am a bit lost on what is going on because my static files seems to be where they should be but nginx cannot find them, altough the path to them is the right one.

```
GET https://www.exostock.net/staticfiles/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

and

```
Home:136 GET https://www.exostock.net/staticfiles/img/logo8.png 404 (Not Found)
```

from the information I read and the django + nginx documentations, I am not able to spot where I am making a mistake. I have been on it for a few days now and I hope that someone could see what I cannot.

nginx/sites-available/app.conf

```
server {
    server_name  exostock.net www.exostock.net;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/exostocksaas/app.sock;
}
        location /static/ {
        alias /home/ubuntu/exostocksaas/collected_static/;
}
location ~ \.css {
   add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
}
location ~ \.js {
    add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
}
}
```

settings.py in django

```
STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/'

# STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
#     'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
#     )
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'collected_static')
```

and my html links to statics

```
   <!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
    <link href="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <!-- Font Awesome CSS-->
    <link href="{% static 'vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}">
    <!-- Custom Font Icons CSS-->

    <link href="{% static 'css3/font.css' %}">
```

UPDATE: I made the changes suggested, but it still not working, when I look into nginx error log, it shows the path to static is the following

```
"/usr/share/nginx/html/staticfiles/
```

this is wrong because if i go look inside of the html folder, there is only the "welcome to nginx" htlm page. The question is why is nginx searching files over there? I have deleted the default file but the error log keeps pointing even after restarting nginx, the server too.

Comment: Have you tried running `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: yes and it works fine, all my statics are collected

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a few issues with confusion on the path names you have selected. If you alter your nginx `app.conf` to:

```
server {
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/exostocksaas;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
    }
}
```

Then alter your `settings.py` file to:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
#     'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
#     )
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

It should start serving your static files correctly. From there you could start making incremental changes to pathnames as you wish but this is the standard config I tend to use for my Django deployments.

Comment: hey I made the suggested changes but still get an error, I update my question to reflect whats up

Comment: Hmm are you sure your nginx file is linked or located in the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` directory? Perhaps goto the nginx section of this article and ensure these steps are met https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04 . It looks as though it is searching a location using the default config. Also ensure the nginx service is reloaded and restarted appropriately after each change.

Comment: thank you for the tuto, I have looked at it a lot! i have commented out everything that is in the default file, restarted gunicorn and nginx (sudo service nginx restart) and I someone still get the default path in error.log. what could be up?

Comment: try `sudo systemctl reload nginx` as well but i dont think that's your issue. I dont understand why nginx is looking for 'staticfiles' if you copied my code. It should be going to a directory named 'static' where all the files are stored after running `collectstatic`.

Comment: Could you please confirm that you are storing your files BEFORE running collectstatic in the directory `/staticfiles/` and they are being transferred to `/static/` after running the command.

Answer (score 0):

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
```

add the folder `static` but at the same path where you use it

put in folder static your staticfiles (css , js ,.... ), and add in html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```